# print a unicode latin letter (utf8)

Tags: c++, unicode, utf-8

Using clang++ 3.2.
Try to print  (\u1D586),

```
cout <<  << endl;
```

but got an compiler error:

```
error: expected expression
cout << <U+1D586> << endl;
```

Alternatively,

```
cout << "\u1D586" << endl;
```

got incomplete output :

```
ᵘ6
```

Seems the last '6' is not interpreted together.

What's the cause and how to solve this?

Comment: For one thing, `u8"<character>"` (it's a square for me, so I can't copy it).

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: $ clang++ --version
clang version 3.2 (tags/RELEASE_32/final)
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix

Comment: @chris unless your browser is completely broken, you can indeed copy it. You just cannot see it properly. While various characters may display as a square, they are still different ones and copying preserves their identity, because browsers don't destroy the page source when rendering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\u` is followed by 4 hex digits and in your case you should use `\U` followed by 8 hex digits `\U0001D586`.

Comment: that's right! thanks a lot for pointing that out! Mind explaining the first compiler error a little bit further?

Comment: @cppinitiator, Because `<U+1D586>` is not an expression, like `5`, or `"hello"`, or `x`. It's gibberish.

Comment: @cppinitiator You must forgot a pair of `"` or `'`.

Comment: @johnchen902 Totally, just realized that. need ""